# Accessing Ids for Create Records when flow executes a Partial Save + Fault Element

Tags: visual-workflow, create-records, fault-connector

I am trying to understand how fault paths work with Create Records. As I understand it, Create Elements automatically implements [Partial Save](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_mgmnt_actions_partial_save.htm&release=224&type=5), like Database.Insert can in apex.
Example - I have three records in Collection of type Lead that have not yes been inserted. If I trigger Create Records, and they are all successful, I can immediately see the new Ids, as described by the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_create.htm&type=5).e.g. if I display the collection from Create Leads in a datatable, the Id column is populated

[image]

But if one fails, and I add a fault path, I can see the DML error in the fault path - but even though the other two records were inserted, I can find no trace of their Ids in the collection like I can when the transaction competes without an error. So here when the fault path is triggered by a record with a bad email, the Id column is blank for all three records, but I can see two of them have actually been inserted when I look at the Leads Tab in SFDC.

[image]

So if I wanted to fix the error and just insert that one, I can't easily do it, because I can't easily work out which ones succeeded and filter them out, unlike in Apex where I use the isSuccess flag + get the new Id for each item.

The only workaround I can find is to use the rollback element to roll the whole Create Records back, but I still don't easily know which records the user needs to review and fix before trying again. Is this just a limitation of Create Records, or is there some way of viewing the save results like you can in Apex?